# How do I assign a character to a integer with dict?

Tags: python

new learner to python here.

I am trying to calculate grade letter to gpa. heres my code:

```
grade1 = input()
grade2 = input()
grade3 = input()

grades = { "A": 4,"B":3,"C":2,"D":1,"F":0 }

gradeTotal = (grade1) + (grade2) + (grade3) / 3
print(gradeTotal)
```

I have the dictionary characters set to the integer values I want. but I am getting the error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

Without the division in the gradeTotal calculation, I get just the input put together, so for example AAA instead of 12
I am stuck and no clue where to go. Looking for some hints or help. Thanks!

Comment: You don't even attempt to use your `grades` dictionary. `gradeTotal = grades[grade1] + grades[grade2] + grades[grade3] / 3`

Comment: Although I'm guessing BODMAS is gonna be an issue so you'll want to think about parentheses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the input from the user (which I assume is the letter), but you never convert it to a number using the values in your dictionary.

In a dictionary you have a key and a value, and you retrieve the value by using the name of the key:

```
# Dictionary
value = 4
dict = {"Key": value}

# Get the value:
dictionary_value = dict["Key"] # dictionary_value is now 4
```

What you should do instead is (also notice the placement of the parenthesis to add them together first and then divide):

```
gradeTotal = (grades[grade1] + grades[grade2] + grades[grade3]) / 3
```

I'd also recommend placing [`.upper()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_upper.htm) behind your `input()` to prevent a key error when someone enters a non-capital letter:

```
grade1 = input().upper()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually use the dict at all. Plus the parens are wrong.

```
gradeTotal = (grades[grade1] + grades[grade2] + grades[grade3]) / 3
```